Error: Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'
I am using Spring Data JPA to query with following code. But i do not know why spring send me the error: Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'. Can you help me solve that problem?
This is my code in repository:
 @Query(value = "SELECT \n " +
            "    a.inventory_output_id AS inventoryOutputId, \n " +
            "    a.is_closed AS isClosed, \n" +
            "    a.output_status AS outputStatus, \n " +
            "    a.slip_no AS slipNo, \n " +
            "    a.plan_output_date AS planOutputDate, \n " +
            "    a.batch_status AS batchStatus, \n " +
            "    MIN(a.order_date) AS orderDateFrom, \n " +
            "    MAX(a.order_date) AS orderDateTo, \n " +
            "    a.actual_output_date AS actualOutputDate, \n " +
            "    a.plan_working_date AS planWorkingDate, \n " +
            "    a.plan_deliver_date AS planDeliverDate, \n " +
            "    a.actual_deliver_date AS actualDeliverDate, \n " +
            "    b.destination_code AS destinationCode, \n " +
            "    b.department_name AS departmentName, \n " +
            "    d.customer_code AS customerCode, \n " +
            "    d.customer_name AS customerName,  \n " +
            "    f.repository_code AS repositoryCode, \n " +
            "    f.repository_name AS repositoryName, \n " +
            "    a.plan_supplier_slip_no AS planSupplierSlipNo, \n " +
            "    a.actual_supplier_slip_no AS actualSupplierSlipNo, \n " +
            "    a.sum_plan_quantity AS sumPlanQuantity, \n " +
            "    a.sum_actual_quantity AS sumActualQuantity \n " +
            "FROM \n " +
            "    t_inventory_output a\n " +
            "         JOIN \n " +
            "    m_customer_delivery_dest b ON a.plan_customer_delivery_destination_id = b.delivery_destination_id \n " +
            "        OR a.actual_customer_delivery_destination_id = b.delivery_destination_id \n " +
            "         JOIN \n " +
            "    m_customer d ON a.plan_customer_id = d.customer_id \n " +
            "        OR a.actual_customer_id = d.customer_id \n " +
            "         JOIN \n " +
            "    m_repository f ON a.plan_repository_id = f.repository_id \n " +
            "        OR a.actual_repository_id = f.repository_id \n " +
            "        JOIN \n " +
            "    t_inventory_plan_output_detail h ON a.inventory_output_id = h.inventory_output_id \n " +
            "        JOIN \n " +
            "    t_inventory_actual_output_detail k ON a.inventory_output_id = k.inventory_output_id \n " +
            "        JOIN \n " +
            "    m_supplier l ON h.supplier_id = l.supplier_id \n " +
            "        JOIN \n " +
            "    m_product m ON l.supplier_id = m.supplier_id \n " +
            " WHERE \n  " +
            "    a.order_date BETWEEN :orderDateFrom AND :orderDateTo \n " +
            "        AND a.plan_output_date BETWEEN :planOutputDateFrom AND :planOutputDateTo \n " +
            "        AND a.plan_working_date BETWEEN :planWorkingDayFrom AND :planWorkingDayTo \n " +
            "        AND a.plan_deliver_date BETWEEN :planDeliverDateFrom AND :planDeliverDateTo \n " +
            "        AND a.slip_no BETWEEN :slipNoFrom AND :slipNoTo \n " +
            "        AND (a.plan_customer_id BETWEEN :customerIdFrom AND :customerIdTo \n " +
            "        OR a.actual_customer_id BETWEEN :customerIdFrom AND :customerIdTo) \n " +
            "        AND d.customer_name LIKE CONCAT('%', :customerName, '%') \n " +
            "        AND (a.plan_customer_delivery_destination_id BETWEEN :destinationIdFrom AND :destinationIdTo \n  " +
            "        OR a.actual_customer_delivery_destination_id BETWEEN :destinationIdFrom AND :destinationIdTo) \n  " +
            "        AND b.department_name LIKE CONCAT('%', :departmentName, '%') \n  " +
            "        AND f.repository_id BETWEEN :repositoryIdFrom AND :repositoryIdTo \n  " +
            "        AND l.supplier_id BETWEEN :supplierIdFrom AND :supplierIdTo \n  " +
            "        AND l.supplier_name LIKE CONCAT('%', :supplierName, '%') \n  " +
            "        AND m.product_id BETWEEN :productIdFrom AND :productIdTo \n  " +
            "        AND (m.name1 LIKE CONCAT('%', :productName, '%') \n " +
            "        OR m.name2 LIKE CONCAT('%', :productName, '%') \n " +
            "        OR m.name3 LIKE CONCAT('%', :productName, '%') \n " +
            "        OR m.name4 LIKE CONCAT('%', :productName, '%') \n " +
            "        OR m.name5 LIKE CONCAT('%', :productName, '%')) \n " +
            "        AND h.batch_no LIKE CONCAT('%', :batchNo, '%') \n " +
            "AND a.is_closed = :isClosed \n " +
            "GROUP BY a.inventory_output_id,a.slip_no \n  " +
            "ORDER BY a.slip_no ASC ", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<OutputListDto> getSearchOutputList(@Param("orderDateFrom") String orderDateFrom,
                                            @Param("orderDateTo") String orderDateTo,
                                            @Param("planOutputDateFrom") String planOutputDateFrom,
                                            @Param("planOutputDateTo") String planOutputDateTo,
                                            @Param("planWorkingDayFrom") String planWorkingDayFrom,
                                            @Param("planWorkingDayTo") String planWorkingDayTo,
                                            @Param("planDeliverDateFrom") String planDeliverDateFrom,
                                            @Param("planDeliverDateTo") String planDeliverDateTo,
                                            @Param("slipNoFrom") String slipNoFrom,
                                            @Param("slipNoTo") String slipNoTo,
                                            @Param("customerIdFrom") Integer customerIdFrom,
                                            @Param("customerIdTo") Integer customerIdTo,
                                            @Param("customerName") String customerName,
                                            @Param("destinationIdFrom") Integer destinationIdFrom,
                                            @Param("destinationIdTo") Integer destinationIdTo,
                                            @Param("departmentName") String departmentName,
                                            @Param("supplierIdFrom") Integer supplierIdFrom,
                                            @Param("supplierIdTo") Integer supplierIdTo,
                                            @Param("supplierName") String supplierName,
                                            @Param("productIdFrom") Integer productIdFrom,
                                            @Param("productIdTo") Integer productIdTo,
                                            @Param("productName") String productName,
                                            @Param("repositoryIdFrom") Integer repositoryIdFrom,
                                            @Param("repositoryIdTo") Integer repositoryIdTo,
                                            @Param("batchNo") String batchNo,
                                            @Param("isClosed") String isClosed,
                                            Pageable pageable
    );


When spring start, i saw it render that line in console view, but i do not why it render "count(a)" in select field
Like this code below:
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(a) 
    FROM
        t_inventory_output a           
    JOIN
        m_customer_delivery_dest b 
            ON a.plan_customer_delivery_destination_id = b.delivery_destination_id           
            OR a.actual_customer_delivery_destination_id = b.delivery_destination_id            

